# /etc/network/interfaces file not found

Tags: ubuntu, ipv4

I am running ubuntu in a Virtualbox VM. I have configured the interface via the GUI(and it works as expected). However, I can't find  /etc/network/interfaces file.
then where can i find  primary configuration files for  ipv4 network interface
.
linux version:20.04
.
<note:i have recently started learning linux>

Comment: Hi, welcome to superuser. For questions like this you need to include your Ubuntu version. For 20.04 your configuration is probably in /etc/netplan/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file /etc/network/interfaces is not an universal standard. Almost every Linux distribution has its own tool for configuring networks – this file is used specifically by the 'ifupdown' tools from Debian.

Recently, however, Ubuntu has switched from ifupdown to [Netplan](https://netplan.io/examples), so **`/etc/netplan/*.yaml`** is the new location for network settings (and the syntax is completely different).

Other Linux distributions may have their own locations as well. For example, Gentoo uses netifrc which is configured through /etc/conf.d/net, and various distros using systemd-networkd would keep configuration in /etc/systemd/network.